# Anonymous function and closures in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I' have this code, know  that require anonymus closure function, but don't understand how it works. If I run it there is a `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.
Can some one explain me anonymus closure functions with the help of this code?

```
mysql= require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({});

function check_auth(input, callback){
 var sql = "query to mysql";
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    if (results.length  > 0) {
        callback(null,results.values); //this is the line with error
    }else{
        callback(null, false);
    } 
  });
  };
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(5678);
  io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
    check_auth(req.query.s, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('error:(');

        }
        if(result === false) {
            return callback('notauth', false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, result);;
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good, but you have an error in your code: missing ); };

```
mysql= require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({});

function check_auth(input, callback){
    var sql = "query to mysql";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        if (results.length  > 0) {
            callback(null,results.values); //this is the line with error
        }else{
            callback(null, false);
        } 
    }); // missing );
}; // missing };

io.configure(function () {
io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
check_auth(req.query.s, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('error:(');

        }
        if(result === false) {
            return callback('notauth', false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, result);;
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added it but is only a copy and paste error, the code don't works

Comment: if you change check_auth to  function check_auth(callback){return callback(null , true); }; does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be scoping issue in your code.  You can't really call a function from another scope without referencing that scope. if you do:

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
    var check_auth = function(...) {};   // <=== local defined

    // then you can call this way
    check_auth(...);
  }
}
```

Since your check_auth() is defined outside, the callback of io.set() has its own scope, it doesn't know anything about check_auth().  So you have to point to the scope that has check_auth() defined.  Something like this:

```
var me = this;          // <==== scope that has check_auth defined
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {

    // then you can call this way
    me.check_auth(...);
  }
}
```

Or you can do closure approach by assigning check_auth to a variable and call it inside the callback.  Something like this:

```
var check_auth = function(...) {};
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {

    // then you can call this way
    check_auth(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to execute the mysql call befor check it

Comment: Then you need to call check_auth() inside the callback of mysql

Comment: i don't undestand your approach

Comment: Ok, let's make sure I understand what you really want to do.  Currently, inside check_auth(), connection.query() is called.  From your 1st comment, you want to call connection.query() then call check_auth()... but then that's what check_auth() does.  It checks by calling connection.query().

Comment: my goal is authorize a user with a mysql query, the problem is check_auth function is async so io.set('authorization') is executed before check_auth return a result

Comment: Ok, what you really need to do is inside the callback function of connection.query(), you want to call io.set() there (right before callback(null,results.values)).  That guarantees that query is done before io.set().

Comment: the problem is that io.set return value for mysql select so te timeline is: connect->pass value to mysql query->check user->if user is ok continue else disconnect

Comment: What's io anyway?  Where did you get it from?

Comment: var io = require('socket.io').listen(5678);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54249/discussion-between-ben-and-alberto-alibaba).